# Is there a way of constraining a functor's parameter signature so the parameter can supply unspecified equality types to a structure?

Tags: types, module, sml, equality, smlnj

If I try to write a parameterized module that calls `=` on an unspecified type supplied by the parameter, SML/NJ throws a type error. E.g., if I have a signature

```
signature SIG =
sig
  type t
end
```

and try to parameterize a module `F` over a module `S` with the signature `SIG`

```
functor F (S : SIG) =
struct
  fun f (x:S.t) (y:S.t) = (x = y)
end
```

I will trigger the following compilation error:

```
Error: operator and operand don't agree [equality type required]
  operator domain: ''Z * ''Z
  operand:         S.t * S.t
  in expression:
    x = y
```

How can I specify that `S.t` should be an equality type?

The only workaround I have been able to figure out so far is to also supply the equality function in the structure over which the functor is parameterized i.e.:

```
signature SIG' =
sig
  type t
  val eq : (''a * ''a) -> bool
end

functor F' (S' : SIG') =
struct
  fun f' x y = S'.eq (x, y)
end


structure A = F'( struct
                    type t = int
                    val eq = (op =)
                  end )
```

It seems like there must be a better way, although I may also be misunderstanding something basic and important about how functors are meant to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need to specify that `t` is an `eqtype`:

```
signature SIG =
sig
  eqtype t
end
```

Comment: O jeez! I don't know how I've never encountered that keyword before! I must not be doing an excellent job of reading the documentation. Thank you!